# What does the region enclosed by $y = 1/x^5 , y=0, x=3, x=4$ look like?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

I'm having trouble trying to see what the region I'm supposed to be computing looks like.

> The volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by
>
> $$y = 1/x^5 , y=0, x=3, x=4$$
>
> about the line $x=−4$ can be computed using the method of cylindrical
> shells via an integral. What does the integrand look like?

Given all the parameters I decided to visualize this first with the graphs. Here are all the curves:

[image]

So everything is being rotated around the black line on the left, $x=-4$. But there are many things that just don't make sense to me:

1. The red function, $y=1/x^5$ isn't even well defined at $x=0$, as it approaches infinity. How is this region "enclosed" at all?
2. The purple line on the far right, $x=4$, doesn't seem to contribute anything to the enclosure, does it? It's just a step after $x=3$ which already limits the volume of the solid.
3. Whatever this solid is, it doesn't seem to be enclosed in any way whatsoever to me. I see that it is limited by $y=0$ at the bottom, but there's nothing bounding it at the top as all the curves just continue straight up.

I already know that the answer is

$$\int\frac{2\pi(4+x)}{x^5}dx$$

But I can't see the reasoning behind the question at all. What does the region look like, and how is it enclosed?

Comment: you have to only look at the region between $3 \leq x \leq 4$ bound above by the curve $y = \frac{1}{x^5}$ and below by $y = 0$. That is being revolved around $x = -4$.

Comment: the upper bound of $y$ is really small compared to the scale that the sketch uses so it is not really visible.

Comment: Anything $x<3$ does not matter to the region.  You are only interested in the tiny speck in your graph which both $3\leq x\leq 4$ and $0\leq y\leq 1/x^5$ are satisfied.  [Plot in WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D1%2Fx%5E5%2C+y%3D0%2C+x%3D3%2C+x%3D4+from+x%3D2.9+to+4.1%2C+y%3D-0.001+to+0.005)

Comment: Oh my god I see it now after zooming all the way in. This problem is just evil.

Comment: No, it is a FUN problem. Washer method

Comment: I think the last equation defining the region should be $y=4$ and not $x=4.$

Answer (score 1):

You might find [Calcplot3D](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html?type=volrev;volrev=x;visible=true;alpha=-1;view=0;top2d=1/x%5E5;bot2d=0;umin=3;umax=4;axisvar=x;axisval=-4;revsliderval=0;grid=15,40;polarform=t;polartop=2;polarbottom=0;polarmin=%CF%80/4;polarmax=3%CF%80/4&type=window;hsrmode=0;nomidpts=true;anaglyph=-1;center=5,3,10;focus=0,0,0,1;up=0,2,0;transparent=false;alpha=140;twoviews=false;unlinkviews=false;axisextension=0.7;xaxislabel=x;yaxislabel=y;zaxislabel=z;edgeson=true;faceson=true;showbox=true;showaxes=true;showticks=true;perspective=true;centerxpercent=0.5;centerypercent=0.5;rotationsteps=30;autospin=true;xygrid=false;yzgrid=false;xzgrid=false;gridsonbox=true;gridplanes=false;gridcolor=rgb(128,128,128);xmin=-15;xmax=5;ymin=0;ymax=0.0045;zmin=-10;zmax=10;xscale=2;yscale=1;zscale=2;zcmin=-4;zcmax=4;zoom=0.151467;xscalefactor=1;yscalefactor=2000;zscalefactor=1) useful for this type of problem.  You can add a surface of revolution, and with enough manipulation of the axes/scales you can produce plots like this:

[image]

It will also be useful to have the [rotation and key shortcuts page](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/CalcPlot3D-Help/section-2.html) for reference.